# PHP IMAP_SEARCH syntax UNSEEN, SINCE, RECENT, produces unexpected results

Tags: php, search, syntax, imap, keyword

I am trying to get a list of the most recent unseen messages from a particular email address.

```
$imapResource = GmailAdapter::imapLogin();

$imapEmails = imap_search($imapResource, 'FROM "email@lala.com" SINCE "18-Mar-2019"');

            if (is_array($imapEmails))
            {
                rsort($imapEmails);

                foreach ($imapEmails as $emailIdent)
                {
                    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($imapResource, $emailIdent, 0);
                    $header = imap_header($imapResource, $emailIdent);
                    $subject = $header->subject;
                    $message = imap_fetchbody($imapResource, $emailIdent, '1');
                    $messageExcerpt = substr($message, 0, 150);
                    $partialMessage = trim(quoted_printable_decode($messageExcerpt));
                    $date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($overview[0]->date));

                    dump($overview);
                    dump($message);
                    dump($subject);
                    dump($date);
                }
                imap_close($imapResource);
            }
```

I have tried SINCE, RECENT, SEARCH RECENT, SEARCH SINCE, UNSEEN and many combinations of these but they all bring up empty arrays.  It seems as soon as I use any of the aforementioned keywords, gmail just says "fuck no" and gives me nothing.

I also tried many different date formats,  still nothing.

If I use exclusively

```
'FROM "email_address"'
```

it works, but it gives me a subset of email id's spanning from 2012 to 2018 march 6th,  so I can't even work with that as I want all the recent emails from a from address.

I've done some looking around on google and here, and it seems nobody has a good answer.

Can anyone shed some light on this, and other similar issues with php IMAP? Why is it so quirky?

UPDATE

I just tried using search term 'ALL' and curiously, it gave me the same last msgno as using my FROM query; 1,000,000, dated March 6th, 2018. Of course, this time, the messages were consecutive,(1,000,000, then 999,999, etc) Which is as it should  be when asking for 'ALL' messages. But i wonder, Is this some sort of limitation with gmail?
Could I grab messages > 1,000,000 somehow?

UPDATE #2
Confirmed, gmail has a limitation, if you have more than 1 million emails in a mailbox, it will not grab more than 1,00,000, starting from oldest first, which causes problems like I'm having. Still though, those search keywords don't give me anything it should, for example RECENT, or UNSEEN. The solution seems to involve making sure you have less than a million messages, if you want to grab anything recent. I'm attempting the same on a gmail that has much less than 1,000,000 emails and see what happens.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for a self answer, especially if appears that it only searches the first million messages.

Comment: I am also curious if you do something like `SEARCH 1000000:* [other flags]` if it would be able to resume the search from there, or if it just is a hard cut off.

Comment: not only does it only search up to 1 million, if you have a criteria like FROM and you know for a fact there isn't 1 million matching emails, it'll still say total messages is 1000000.  I didn't try anything else b/c quite frankly, I can't waste more time on this. So my solution is this: "Warning If you happen to have more than a million messages in your inbox, you might have difficulty retrieving recent messages. This is a gmail quirk. It's recommended to make sure you have less than 800k emails."   lol  Anyway, it works normally if < 1000000

Comment: but this still doesn't solve the mystery or why "SEEN" or "RECENT" don't work.  Seems everyone has this problem to some degree.

Comment: I use `UNSEEN` and it works fine, but presumably it's only searching the first million mails.  If you only have unseen in recent emails, presumably none of them fit in your window.